# Transform SOAP to HTML with XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, soap

I'm trying to convert this SOAP response to simple HTML:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <Players xmlns="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">
         <Player>
            <name>ATP</name>
            <ranking>1</ranking>
            <first_name>Novak</first_name>
            <last_name>Djokovic</last_name>
            <country>RS</country>
            <email>novak@aaa.net</email>
         </Player>
         <Player>
            <name>ATP</name>
            <ranking>2</ranking>
            <first_name>Andy</first_name>
            <last_name>Murray</last_name>
            <country>GB</country>
            <email>andy@bbb.net</email>
         </Player>
         <Player>
            <name>ATP</name>
            <ranking>3</ranking>
            <first_name>Viktor</first_name>
            <last_name>Troicki</last_name>
            <country>US</country>
            <email>viktor@ccc.com</email>
         </Player>
      </Players>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

This is my XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:p="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice"
exclude-result-prefixes="p">
<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>
  <h2>PLAYER RANKINGS</h2>
    <table border="1">
      <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
        <th style="text-align:left">Ranking</th>
        <th style="text-align:left">First Name</th>
        <th style="text-align:left">Last Name</th>
        <th style="text-align:left">Country</th>
      </tr>
      <xsl:for-each select="//p:Players/Player">
      <tr>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="p:ranking"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="p:first_name"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="p:last_name"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="p:country"/></td>
      </tr>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I'm "playing" with this simple task for a long time but can't make it match the select expression in for-loop.

I tried both with and without namespaces, but with no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed a namespace. Try

```
<xsl:for-each select="//p:Players/p:Player">
```